# How to Anchor large 3D models in ARKit (Unity)?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

I am new to ARKit and I'm using Unity along with it.

So I just got one of my custom models to be displayed and I can anchor it to the ground by tapping on a discovered plane. However my model is pretty big, its a life sized shack.

The problem is when I move around to much the model loses its anchor point and becomes unstable and starts moving around all over the place. This wasn't a problem when I had it as a smaller model, only when I scaled it up.

Has anyone else had this problem? Have you gotten it to work?
Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of inherent to the plane detection. If you look up at the ceiling for instance it is no longer seeing the floor and it is basicly only using the phones gyroscope and accelerator to know how the phone has moved. As far as i know there is no real solution to this since the object is only anchored to the detected plane.